# I have created a Button but can't find which command to use to change it

Tags: python, button, tkinter, command

I have already created a `Button` using this code:

```
btnLuxury=Button(f1,padx=16,pady=8,bd=16, fg="black",font=('arial', 16,'bold'),width=10,
                 text="Luxury", bg="powder blue", command = Luxury).grid(row=8,column=3)
```

but when I click on it, it does nothing. Now I want it to display the amount `8000` in the text box of total amount. What do I type after `def`?

Comment: You should include your `Luxury()` function in your post. That seems very important in this situation

Comment: @Keval India could you please include your `Luxury()` function in your post because it will make it easier to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is either in your `Luxury()` function that wasn't provided, or the setup of your `btnLuxury` variable. A better approach would be:

```
btnLuxury=Button(f1,padx=16,pady=8,bd=16, fg="black",font=('arial', 16,'bold'),width=10, text="Luxury", bg="powder blue", command=Luxury)
btnLuxury.grid(row=8,column=3)
```

Where the creation of your `Button` and the gridding of it are separate. Otherwise the `.grid()` method is called (which returns `None`) and the result (again `None`) is assigned to the value `btnLuxury` then later when you try to alter the text of the widget or whatever, you will basically be calling `None.configure()` whereas with my code above you would be calling `Button.configure()` instead

Comment: If you can, could you please give me your email or messenger or whatsapp details so i can send you some images of the code and program as i am not able to send images here and without them it will be confusing to understand

Comment: @KevalIndia You should keep your posts on here so other people can see them when they encounter a similar problem in the future. Maybe you need to review [how to make a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: yes i know but there is no way to explain my problem without having a look at my code and the outcome program

Comment: @KevalIndia That's why you can include code and a picture of the result in your post...

Comment: Ok from the beginning.

Comment: Ok from the beginning.
1. I have two buttons. 1 is a Reset Button and the second one is a Luxury or lets now call it a Total amount button. 

My def for the Reset button is ;  def Reset():
        rand.set("") 
        WallHeight.set("")
        Wall1Lenght.set("")
        Wall2Lenght.set("")
        Wall3Lenght.set("")
        Wall4Lenght.set("")
        WindowHeight.set("")
        WindowLength.set("")
        Luxury.set("")
        Standard.set("")
        Economy.set("")
        Undercoat.set("")
        TotalArea.set("")
        TotalAmount.set("") 
This works perfectly.

Comment: Now my def for the Luxury button is;
def Luxury():
    Luxury.set(8000)

and my code for the button size name and all is;
btnLuxury=Button(f2,padx=16,pady=8,bd=16, fg="black",font=('arial', 16,'bold'),width=10,
                text="Luxury", bg="powder blue", command = Luxury).grid(row=2,column=0)

Now the rest button works perfectly because the def is correct. but the Luxury button dosent work because def is wrong. So what def should i use

Comment: You should not post these as comments. Please edit your post so it is readable instead!